# How to route only certain traffic through OpenVpn

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I am using Hackthebox academy to learn hacking. In this site, we can host virtual machines for absolutely free. it also teaches you how to hack. But, hackthebox needs to use OpenVpn to connect the virtual machine to my home WiFi network. But, when I connect it, I am disconnected from the internet. How can I make it so that the internet data is not sent over the vpn but the rest of the data is?

Comment: Delete thecdefault gateway associated with the VPN or use  2 * /1 subnets  through to your router to be a more more specific path then the default gateway.

Comment: You might get more teactuon on tjis site if you eliminated refs to hacking - hacking is not relevant to your question and many of us are loathe to answer questions painted with a "hacking" brush.

Answer (score 0):

As a person who has used hackthebox before, I think you are doing something wrong to get disconnected. When I first started, I added the OpenVPN file to the settings and turned it on from there. That is wrong. If you added it like that, first delete the vpn from settings. Then, type this command:- `openvpn <filename>.ovpn`. This worked for me.